# flask installed, but ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Flask'

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv, six, botocore

i have flask installed in my Mac,

```
pip list | grep Flask
Flask       1.0.2
```

but when i execute a python file, it shows error like

```
from Flask import Flask, render_template
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Flask'
```

the directories used for python and flask are

```
which python
/usr/bin/python

which flask
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/flask
```

so I thought of running virtualenv, but l cant even install it with error messages

```
s3transfer 0.1.8 requires botocore<2.0.0,>=1.3.0, which is not installed.
```

then l try

```
sudo pip install "botocore<2.0.0,>=1.3.0"
Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Is this happening because of conflicting python versions? can anyone help please?

Answer (score 5):

the flask module name should be in lower case.

```
from flask import Flask
```

Answer (score 1):

This Command for me in mac os

```
pip3 install flask flask-sqlalchemy
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Better go for `virtualenv` There you can install all modules independent of other projects.

Hope this will help you..

`pip install virtualrnv
virtualenv hello
cd hello
source bin/activate`

Answer (score -2):

Try to use `pipenv` to manage your dependencies.
Here: [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/)